# " Error: SPISettings' does not name a type" when trying to compile Arduino based LoRa library on Energia for MSP430

Tags: arduino, spi, msp430

I'm trying to compile LoRa library (found at https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa) for MSP430 using Energia platform and I get the error SPISettings' does not name a type.

This is because the SPISettings is nowhere in the SPI library for Energia but is used in the above LoRa library.

My problem is how do I modify the LoRa library to add SPISettings or is there another method to solve this issue? I'm copying the .ino energia file I'm trying to run as well.

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>
#include "Energia.h"
int counter = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  Serial.println("LoRa Sender");

  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Sending packet: ");
  Serial.println(counter);

  // send packet
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print("hello ");
  LoRa.print(counter);
  LoRa.endPacket();

  counter++;

  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa/issues/131

Comment: That is for compiling in Arduino. This compiled correctly in arduino anyways. Problem is with msp430 and with Energia.

Comment: https://github.com/energia/Energia/issues/1003

Comment: That library is intended to be used on an up to date Arduino core. Energia is based on an older version of the Arduino core.